# Is there anyway to use mongodb to search for ANY instead of omit the query?

Tags: mongodb

Is there anyway to use mongodb to search for ANY instead of omit the query.
Example

```
 db.users.find({country:"Vietnam", gender:ANY}).pretty()
```

instead of

```
db.users.find({country:"Vietnam"}).pretty()
```

Comment: To what purpose? Why would "omitting any constraint" not be the correct thing to do in your eyes? The question suggests a different problem that you are not actually asking about.

Comment: For advance search that use can filter what they search for. So gender can be male, female or any.

Comment: What is "advance search"? At a guess you are probably asking in the context that maybe not "ALL" UI choices would be selected for "ALL" possible query parameters. But the solution there is **not** to use an **ANY** option, but rather to "construct the query dynamically" based on the selected options. My main point being "explain your case better in your question". That is if you still do not understand what "dynamic construction" means.

Comment: got it. Thank you!